# Extract named groups from file name and version

Tags: .net, regex, regular-language

I have the following case where file names can be the following format

`filename.majorver.minorver.hotfix.rev`

filename = can contain alpha numeric with `-` `_` and `.`

majorver, minorver, hotifx = 1 to 9 digits only

rev = can exist or not but if exists 1 to 9 digits only

The regex I have with named groups is the following

```
 var regexPattern = @"(?<name>\w+).(?<major>[0-9]{1,9}).(?<minor>[0-9]{1,9}).(?<hotfix>[0-9]{1,9})(.(?<rev>[0-9]{1,9}))?";
 var regex = new Regex(regexPattern);

 var match = regex.Match("somefile.10000.210");

 var name = match.Groups["name"].Value;
 var major = match.Groups["major"].Value;
 var minor = match.Groups["minor"].Value;
 var hotfix = match.Groups["hotfix"].Value;
 var rev = match.Groups["rev"].Value;
```

For some reason the above match passes even though `hotfix` is required. I am not able to pass it for the below cases

a) filename.ext.10.2.12

b) filename.ext.10.2.12.3

c) filename-name.10.2.

Any idea how to approach this ?

Comment: Use anchors `^` and `$` or add `(?<!\S)` to beginning of your regex and `(?!\S)` to the end. Besides, escape that dots.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't apply boundaries, engine will start match whenever there is one. So you have to options. If filenames are each a separate input or each on a separate line use (enable `m` flag if latter is the case):

```
^REGEX$
```

Or if they are every where in a text:

```
(?<!\S)REGEX(?!\S)
```

You have to escape dots too.

> filename = can contain alpha numeric with `-` `_` and `.`

You didn't add those characters to character class. You should include them:

```
(?<name>[\w.-]+?)
               ^ Lazy quantifier
```

Modified regex:

```
^(?<name>[\w.-]+?)\.(?<major>[0-9]{1,9})\.(?<minor>[0-9]{1,9})\.(?<hotfix>[0-9]{1,9})(\.(?<rev>[0-9]{1,9}))?$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lVr6SG/1)